# Removing Rules from crawl spider

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm wondering what difference it can make if I delete the crawl spider rules from the code.
My code works fine without them, but is this the wrong use?

This is the rules section that I deleted :
rules = (
Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_css=''),  callback='parse_item', follow=True)
)

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.http import Request, FormRequest


class AutogonCrawlSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'xxxxxx_crawl'

    allowed_domains = ['xxxxxxx.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.xxxxxxxx.com/xxxxx']
    login_page = 'https://www.xxxxxxxx.com/xxxx/xxxxx'


    def start_requests(self):
        """This function is called before crawling starts."""
        yield Request(url=self.login_page, callback=self.login, dont_filter=True)

    def login(self, response):
        """Generate a login request."""
        yield FormRequest.from_response(
                    response,
                    formdata={'email': 'xxxxxxx', 'password': 'xxxxxxxxx'},
                    callback=self.check_login_response)

    def check_login_response(self, response):
        """Check the response returned by a login request to see if we are
        successfully logged in.
        """
        if "success" in str(response.body):
            print("Successfully logged in. Let's start crawling!")
            # Now the crawling can begin..
            yield Request(url=self.start_urls[0], callback=self.parse_item, dont_filter=True)
        else:
            print("Bad times :(")
            # Something went wrong, we couldn't log in, so nothing happens.


    def parse_item(self, response):
       # the rest of the code
```

Comment: It doesn't matter here because it first go to `start_requests` and from there callback to the rest of the functions in order, you could also use `scrapy.Spider`, the rules doesn't play a part in this code because you restrict them to everything. In other program it could make a lot of difference. Read about [crawlSpider](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider) and [scrapy.Spider](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy-spider).

Comment: Ok thank you so much. I need to ask you something else plese about looping over the links.